# Nutch - Getting Error: JAVA_HOME is not set. when trying to crawl

Tags: java, hadoop, cassandra, nutch, emr

First and foremost I'm a Nutch/Hadoop newbie. I have installed Cassandra. I have installed Nutch on the Master node of my EMR cluster. When I attempt to execute a crawl using the following command:

```
sudo bin/crawl crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5
```

I get

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.
```

If I run the command without 'sudo' I get:

```
    Injector: starting at 2014-07-16 02:12:24
Injector: crawlDb: urls/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: crawl
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Injector: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/hadoop/apache-nutch-1.8/runtime/local/crawl
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:1081)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1073)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$700(JobClient.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:983)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:910)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1353)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:279)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.run(Injector.java:316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:306)
```

I cannot figure this out. I've seen the other forum here: [Similar Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374028/cant-get-apache-nutch-to-crawl-permissions-and-java-home-suspected)

and followed it to no avail. I have added

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

and

```
export PATH=$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
```

to my ~/.bashrc and I am using Linux..

Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I was running

```
sudo bin/crawl crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5
```

I used

```
bin/crawl ./urls/seed.txt TestCrawl http://localhost:8983/solr/ 5
```

And all is well, just a malformed command.. i.e. 'crawl' is deprecated as stated here: [Apache Nutch Tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial)