# Nutch 1.7 JAVA_HOME not set Error

Tags: apache, nutch, web-crawler, java-home

I'm experimenting **Apache Nutch 1.7** and **Solr** on **Ubuntu 14.04 x64 (AMD) LTS** and when i try to run Nutch, it gives me this error message:

> Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.

But when i type **echo $JAVA_HOME** command on terminal, it gives me this path:
**/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64**

Below you can see what i've done step by step. How can i fix this?

***ps**: Ubuntu is a virtual machine which runs on Mac with Oracle VirtualBox

1. Intalling java on terminal with **sudo apt-get -y install openjdk-7-jdk**
2. Checking java installation by **java -version** command
3. Setting JAVA_HOME with:
4. **sudo nano /etc/environment**
5. Then typing following line at the bottom of file: **JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"**
6. kntrl+X shortcut for Saving changes.
7. Then this command: **source /etc/environment**
8. Now JAVA_HOME must be set. I checked it by following command and it gives me the path. **echo $JAVA_HOME** and output is same as above.
9. Then i installed Solr by **sudo apt-get -y install solr-tomcat**
10. I controlled installation by typing this address in a browser: **`http://localhost:8080/solr`** and it shows me initial page of solr
11. I downloaded Apache Nutch 1.7 from http://nutch.apache.org and file was named as apache-nutch-1.7.-bin.tar.gz
12. Then extract it: **tar -zxvf apache-nutch-1.7-bin.tar.gz**
13. I verfied Nutch's installation by simply this:
    **cd apache-nutch-1.7** then 
    **bin/nutch**
    And the output is like **Usage: nutch COMMAND where......**
14. Then i edit my **conf/nutch-site.xml** file as in here: [***Link***](http://www.opensourceconnections.com/blog/2014/05/24/crawling-with-nutch/) (You need to look under this title: "**3) Set Up Your Nutch-Site.Xml**" )
    Things i did different from that last reference are; MyBot  and MyBot,* fields. Instead of *MyBot* i wrote *mySpider*
15. Then i get in conf directory of nutch with Terminal. Here's what i did after:
    **mkdir -p urls** , 
    **cd urls** , 
    **touch seed.txt** , 
    **nano seed.txt**
16. i only wrote this url in the file as it's suggested in official tutorial of nutch:
    http://nutch.apache.org

17After i saved my changed in seed.txt file. I edit the conf/regex-urlfilter.txt file. I delete these two lines:

> ## accept anything else
>
> +.

Then i wrote this instead of them:

> `+^http://([a-z0-9]*\.)*nutch.apache.org/`

After that,

I used this command as it's suggested in tutorial:
**bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5**

**After this command i see this error message:
Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.**

I also found this article but it didn't solve my problem either:
[Nutch - Getting Error: JAVA_HOME is not set. when trying to crawl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771239/nutch-getting-error-java-home-is-not-set-when-trying-to-crawl)

Answer (score 1):

First try: readlink -f $(which java)

That will tell you exactly where your JAVA_HOME is, you should see something like:

```
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

Then try using this value to set your JAVA_HOME just before you call the crawl script i.e.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/ 
bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5
```

note that the value should point to the JRE directory inside a valid JDK location.

p.s. You are missing the Solr URL parameter (in case you want to index the crawled documents of course)